# MySQL users table: find rows that have the same email address

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a users table in MySQL.

```
id | username | email
```

I would like to get the IDs of duplicated users based on the email address. So basically find the Ids of users where the email address can be found more than 1 times in the table.

I wrote something like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM users as users
WHERE (
  SELECT count(id)
  FROM users as users2
  WHERE users.email = users2.email
) > 1
```

It works ok, but very slow, as the query doesn't seem to use the index. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution :

```
select u.id
from users as u
inner join
(    SELECT email
    FROM users
    GROUP BY users.email
    HAVING count(id) > 1
) as u2 on u2.email = u.email
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just return 1 id of a user with a non-unique email in stead of all the id's like the example query?

Comment: Yeah, I also tried that, it only returns 1 id / email, but I would like to get all the Ids.